# How can I simplify this query without "WITH" or Subquery on SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a query that filter my table for positive stock in my warehouse and stores.

I need to take only positive value and if one of values is positive I take this value only.

```
WITH Resultat AS
(
    SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores,
        CASE 
         WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
         WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
         WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
         ELSE StockDepots + StockStores
        END AS StockMulti
    FROM ArticleStock 
)    
SELECT * FROM Resultat
WHERE StockMulti > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref
```

Fiddle :  http://rextester.com/RMSU6120

My query result is Ok, I need to know How can I simplify this query without "WITH" or Subquery ?

EDIT**

Why I don't need WITH or SubQuery is because I think is overkill in this case and I think  it's possible to make this query without WITH or Subquery.

Comment: You think, that a `WITH-CTE` or a Sub-Query is an *overkill*... No, SQL is not a procedural language, where you state a stepwise order of commands. You rather tell the engine what you want and the engine decides which is the most efficient way to get your result. A CTE as well as a subselect would in such easy cases be inlined probably and lead to the same execution plans...

Comment: I agree with you but I wanted to say that writing a CTE is longer and less easy to read than a simple query.

Comment: I must admit, that I do not agree... A CTE is a nice possibility to use calculated columns with speaking names in later query.

Comment: @Shnugo the evaluation with the simple compare can use index thus being more effective. So in this case the execution plan is better.

Comment: Yes but, I don't like use WITH because If I need to re-use this query in Mysql this doesn't work. To go back to what I said, it's true that I find the WITH nice to read

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Sure, that is true... It is a different issue, if you are looking for a way to write **the same query without a CTE or a sub-select** or if you find a **logical enhancement** Using the simple compare is best, as it would not need any sophisticated workarounds at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with a CTE or a sub-select?

Here are some approaches, which should be equivalent:

--Uses row-wise calculation with `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores
      ,ca.StockMulti
FROM ArticleStock 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
                    WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
                    WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
                    ELSE StockDepots + StockStores END) AS ca(StockMulti)
WHERE StockMulti > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref;
```

--Doubles the `CASE`

```
SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores
      ,CASE 
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
        WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
        ELSE StockDepots + StockStores END AS StockMulti
FROM ArticleStock 
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
        WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
        ELSE StockDepots + StockStores END > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref;
```

--If I get this right, it should be enough to check for `WHERE StockStores > 0 OR StockDepots > 0`

```
SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores
      ,CASE 
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
        WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
        WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
        ELSE StockDepots + StockStores END AS StockMulti
FROM ArticleStock 
WHERE StockStores > 0 OR StockDepots > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref;
```

Comment: If i've other condition, I think add "()" in where clause is good :  WHERE (StockStores > 0 OR StockDepots > 0)

Comment: Adding paranthesis here will be a good idea, but the general answer is: *It depends...* :-D

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```
 SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores,
    CASE 
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
     WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
    END AS StockMulti
FROM ArticleStock 
WHERE StockDepots > 0 or StockStores > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref
```

Note that the "else" in the original case statement would never get exercised, because you are only using rows where one of the values is > 0.  I removed it, as it may cause confusion.

Comment: should not be downvoted. Posted same answer (saw yours and deleted mine)

Comment: There is mistake in query on field name : tockStores -> StockStores

Comment: Someone tried to edit the `ELSE` back into the case statement.  I'm definitely sure I don't want it there, and that it makes no difference in the query result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly in where condition:

```
SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores,
    CASE 
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
     WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
     ELSE StockDepots + StockStores
    END AS StockMulti
FROM ArticleStock 
where       (CASE 
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
     WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
     ELSE StockDepots + StockStores
    END) > 0
order by AR_Ref
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push the data into a `Temp Table` and then later use that table in a simple way.

```
SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores,
    CASE 
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
     WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
     WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
     ELSE StockDepots + StockStores
    END AS StockMulti INTO #Test
FROM #ArticleStock 

SELECT * FROM #Test WHERE StockMulti > 0
```

Comment: But I dont seem to find any issues with your coding, any performance issues you are facing ?

Comment: The object of question was to avoid the sub query because it is overkill. Creating a new temporary table is even more overkill

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT AR_Ref,StockDepots,StockStores,
        CASE 
         WHEN StockDepots > 0 AND StockStores > 0  THEN StockDepots + StockStores
         WHEN StockDepots > 0 THEN StockDepots
         WHEN StockStores > 0 THEN StockStores
         ELSE StockDepots + StockStores
        END AS StockMulti
    FROM ArticleStock 
)    
Resultat
WHERE StockMulti > 0
ORDER BY AR_Ref
```

Comment: This is no different than the query in the question

Comment: That was a subquery

Comment: He asked Subquery, thats query inside a query isn't it?

Comment: **without** subquery was the request.

Comment: without *WITH* or using subquery i guess he has written?